# error style-loader@3.2.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 12.13.0". Got "10.19.0"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, css-loader, webpack-style-loader

I'm trying to install css-loader and style-loader in webpack but It shows this error. It seems like my node version is old that's why I tried to upgrade my node version using nvm (Node Version Manager) But I couldn't install nvm in my Linux machine and I ended up uninstalling the nodejs from my system and reinstalled it but still It shows me the following versions.

Nodejs: v10.19.0
Npm: v7.20.5

I'm using Linux ( Ubuntu ) LTS

Can someone please tell me what's the main issue It's not letting me install loaders in webpack? I'm almost new to webpack and I've attached my webpack configuration file below.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { loader: 'babel-loader' },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Well, the package `style-loader` you are trying to install (either directly or as a dependency of some other package) won't work with your current node version (10.19) but wants at least node version 12.13. Update your nodejs to at least that version. Also keep in mind, that node 10 is already outdated and not supported anymore ...

Comment: Actually, I'm using Linux and I tried to upgrade my node version with LTS but It didn't work. Also, I tried to use NVM but the same result.

Comment: If you want a recent version of nodejs, don't install the package that comes with your distribution, but follow the instructions on nodejs.org on how to install a recent version

Comment: Alright, Thanks @derpirscher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to install new packages using distribuition managers.
Using this link https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall, identify what's your linux and its commands to update/install a newer nodejs version.

In my case, Ubuntu with the sequence:

```
    node -v
    10.19.0 // my old version
    # Using Ubuntu
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    node -v
    v16.9.1 // my newest version
```